# How to unhide hidden column in Phabricator workboard?

Tags: phabricator

I hid a column in a Phabricator workboard by clicking on the arrow on the top right of it and selected "Hide Column". Now I would like to unhide it but I don't see any way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I unhid the column by clicking Manage (gear icon on top right of workboard), clicking "Show Hidden Columns", clicking on the arrow on the top right of the column I wanted to unhide, clicking "Show Column", clicking Manage again, and "Hide Hidden Columns".